# Call casperjs capture from DOM context (evaluate)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dom, phantomjs, casperjs

Is there any way to call casperjs methods like capture when function is called from evaluate context ?

Explanation : i want to be able to write js scripts (qunit) that can run both in a "real" browser or in casper.

Sample :

```
function screenshot()(
//i'm runing in a "real" browser ? Then only console.log 
//i'm running in casper ? Then call capser.capture()
```

I tried this with closure but fails :

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
casper.start('http://google.fr/');

casper.evaluate(function(o) {
o.capture('/tmp/google.png', {
    top: 100,
    left: 100,
    width: 500,
    height: 400
});
}, {o: this});

casper.run()


TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.                   
  :/modules/webpage.js:249
  /Users/macbookpro/js:576 in evaluate
  /Users/macbookpro/js/testClosure.js:11
```

I know there's a way to use use console.log as a message bus but i'm searching for a better solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PhantomJS (and thus also CasperJS), `evaluate` runs in a jailed environment. Only primitive objects, something you can serialize via `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` is accepted.

The usual practice is to run the screen capture from your main script. You can still **trigger** the capture from other place, including within `evaluate`, you just need to communicate it back to the main script. Check out PhantomJS included [`run-qunit.js`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/run-qunit.js) example which detects the completion of the tests by monitoring the existence of a particular DOM element.

Comment: Ok so answer is : evaluate can't access to main capserJS objects. I'll try to find another way to let the DOM context talk with Casper, using  return structure or console.log callback.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to run casper methods within `evaluate()`. Here's your code, fixed:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://google.fr/', function() {
    this.capture('google.png', {
        top: 100,
        left: 100,
        width: 500,
        height: 400
    });
});

casper.run()
```